# javascript single line input doesn't stop on each function

Tags: javascript

trying to create single line input field for multiple values with JavaScript. This is my course of doing it. How can I execute each function step by step without jumping to the end?

```
function myFunction() {
  getName();
  getPhone();
  getPickupAddress();
  getDestination();
  getDate();
  getTime();
}

function getName(){
  var client = document.getElementById('CustomerName').value;
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML=client;
  document.getElementById('CustomerName').value='';
}

function getPhone(){
document.getElementById('CustomerName').id='CustomerPhone';  
  document.getElementById('CustomerPhone').placeholder='Your Phone Number';
  var phone = document.getElementById('CustomerPhone').value;
  document.getElementById('CustomerPhone').value='';
}

function getPickupAddress(){
  document.getElementById('CustomerPhone').id='CustomerAddress';
document.getElementById('CustomerAddress').placeholder='Pick Up Address';  
}
function getDestination(){
  document.getElementById('CustomerAddress').id='Destination';
  document.getElementById('Destination').placeholder='Destination';
}
function getDate(){
  document.getElementById('Destination').id='Date';
  document.getElementById('Date').placeholder='Pick Up Date';
}
function getTime(){
  document.getElementById('Date').id='Time';
  document.getElementById('Time').placeholder='Pick Up Time';
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does "*without jumping to the end*" exactly mean?

Comment: when I run myFunction(), I see last function getTime() running on html page. I need to go over each function one by one.

Comment: What triggers the fact that you should run the next function? Anyway, when you have multiple deferred operation to run one after the other, just use a queue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running all the functions at once, put it in the `onChange` of the text field. Then when the field is change it will run it. You may also want to bind the enter key to run your function.

In the onChange or the enter will always call `nextFunction`.

Then set it like this:

```
var nextFunction = getName;
function getName(){
  ..........
  nextFunction = getPhone;
}
```

Do similar for the other functions. Then the function will only run at the right time, and each time it runs it switches to the next function in the list.

Comment: You need to do `nextFunction()` - you forgot the parentheses that make it a function call. But that's not what told you to do anyway, I said to call `nextFunction` from the `onOchange`.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript

```
function getName(){
    var client = document.getElementById('CustomerName').value;
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML="<p>Customer Name: " + client +"</p>";
    document.getElementById('CustomerName').value='';
    document.getElementById('CustomerName').id='CustomerPhone';
    document.getElementById('CustomerPhone').placeholder='Your Phone Number';
    document.getElementById('CustomerPhone').type='tel';
    document.getElementById('myBtn').onclick = getPhone;
}

function getPhone(){

    var phone = document.getElementById('CustomerPhone').value;
    document.getElementById('CustomerPhone').value='';
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML+="<p>Customer Phone: " + phone +"</p>";
    document.getElementById('myBtn').onclick = getEmail;
    document.getElementById('CustomerPhone').id='CustomerEmail';
    document.getElementById('CustomerEmail').placeholder='Your Email';
    document.getElementById('CustomerEmail').type='email';
}
function getEmail(){

    var email = document.getElementById('CustomerEmail').value;
    document.getElementById('CustomerEmail').value='';
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML+="<p>Customer Email: " + email +"</p>";
    document.getElementById('myBtn').onclick = getPickupAddress;
    document.getElementById('CustomerEmail').id='from';
    document.getElementById('from').placeholder='Pick Up Address';
    document.getElementById('from').class='ui-bar-c';
}
```

...

HTML

```
<input type='text' id='CustomerName' name="Customer" placeholder='Your Name'>
<button id="myBtn" onclick='getName()'>next</button>
```